# How do I get to the other Inazuma islands right after getting the travel permit?

Tags: genshin-impact

I completed the quest that gives me the Travel permit that allows me to freely move in Inazuma, but how do I get to the other islands?

I don't see any high points where I can successfully glide from one island to the other, and swimming is completely out of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inazuma is host to a traversal mechanic not available in Mondstadt or Liyue, which makes a lot of sense given the nature of the nation of Inazuma which is a collection of islands separated by vast stretches of water, that being [Waveriders](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Waverider) (i.e. boats) which you can summon via a Waverider Waypoint which looks like this

[image: Waverider Waypoint]

and appears on your map as

[image: Waverider Waypoint Icon]

Which allows you to navigate the seas between the Inazuman isles without needing to glide or swim between them (just don't try sailing a Waverider back to Mondstadt or Liyue lest ye be smote by the lightning of the almighty Shogun)

Comment: I already know that is not possible to go from Inazuma to the rest of Teyvat by sea, as I tried to Kaeya Bridge my way to Inazuma from Liyue and failed miserably. Also, the Waveriders mechanic was not explained anywhere so I didn't knew about it.

Comment: @Lemon Do me a favour, walk up to a Waverider Waypoint and tell me if the tutorial pops up then, this feels like an oversight by MHY if they don't proactively explain Waveriders in Inazuma before new players stumble upon a Waverider Waypoint. I like a fair few players was introduced to Waveriders during patch 1.6 on the Golden Apple Archipelago which was a temporary region that existed only during that patch which explicitly use Waveriders in the story quests so you couldn't miss them

Comment: The tutorial doesn't pops up for me, I only learned about the Waverider quite some time later when I was searching for information about the quest called "Cleansing Defilement", where you need to go to the middle of the ocean.

Comment: From the wiki: "Use the Waverider to head further north towards the flat tide with the wrecked ship."

Comment: @Lemon If you go to your Archive, under Tutorials do you have an entry titled "the mystical waverider"? I received this entry pertaining to Waveriders in patch 1.6 but I do not know when it would have been given (if given at all) to players who started after the Golden Apple Archipelago went away